# Finding a maximum of the product of three integers in a list of any size

Tags: python, list, max, multiplication

I just finished working on this practice problem:

> Given a list of integers, return the largest product that can be made by multiplying any three integers.
> For example, if the list is [-10, -10, 5, 2], we should return 500, since that's -10 * -10 * 5.

I've written the following code and it seems to work, but I feel like it could be simpler somehow. Any ideas?

```
def maxProduct(lst):
    combo = []
    for i in range(0,len(lst)):
        for j in range(0,len(lst)):
            for k in range(0,len(lst)):
                if i != j and j != k and i != k:
                    x = sorted([lst[i]] + [lst[j]] + [lst[k]])
                    if x not in combo: 
                        combo.append(x)
    final = []
    for i in combo:
        result = 1
        for j in i:
            result = result * j
        final.append(result)
             
    return max(final)
```

Comment: Yes, this is certainly more brute-force than is necessary.  One thing you can do is start each subsequent loop at `<prior loop's value> + 1`.  This will save you trying every combination 4 times.

Comment: Isn't this problem equivalent to finding three (or generally `N`) numbers with maximal absolute values given the product of their signs equals one?

Comment: @CaptainTrojan - I thought of that.  It's the `product of their signs equals one` part that prevents the super trivial result of finding the three values with max absolute value.  That's certainly something that could be tried first.  But if the signs don't lead to a positive result, then what do you try next?

Answer (score 1):

Taking a similar "brute force" approach, you can use some built-ins to make this a one-liner (and some imports):

```py
from itertools import combinations
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul
result = max(reduce(mul, p, 1) for p in combinations(arr, 3))
```

Comment: This is an improvement, but doesn't this just optimize the brute-force case?  Aren't all combinations still being tried indiscriminantly?

Comment: @SayandipDutta you're right, the order is irrelevant. Edited and fixed. Thanks for noticing!

Comment: @Steve most certainly. This isn't a smarter algorithm, just an (arguably) neater way to implement the brute-forcing.

Comment: see answer below for an `O(n)` solution... (assuming `k << n` and thus neglecting the `C(2k, k)` combos).

Answer (score 1):

There are only two non-degenerate possibilities, given that the list is of integers:

1. The three maximum positive integers.
2. The maximum positive integer and the two minimum negative integers.

Sort the list.

```
return max( values[-1] * values[-2] * values[-3],
            values[-1] * values[ 0] * values[ 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `x = sorted([lst[i]] + [lst[j]] + [lst[k]])` to `x = sorted([lst[i], lst[j], lst[k]])`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic and yet very fast way (`O(n)` for small `k`) of doing this (< 6ms for 100K elements and `k=3`).

It is *generic* in that you can look for the max product of any `k>0` values (even or odd) if you so chose, not just `k=3`.

The idea is to look for the top `k` and bottom `k` values (`hi`, resp. `lo`). Instead of sorting (`O(n log n)`), we use `heapq` (`O(n)`, used twice) to find `hi` and `lo`.

Usually `hi` will have the most positive values and `lo` will have the most negative values, but it works if there are negatives in `hi` or positives in `lo`. Then we look for `k` combinations among the `2k`-list `hi + lo`.

```py
from itertools import combinations
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul
import heapq

def prod(lst):
    return reduce(mul, lst, 1)

def find_max_prod(lst, k):
    hi = heapq.nlargest(k, lst)
    lo = heapq.nsmallest(min(k, len(lst) - len(pos)), lst)
    return max((prod(vals), vals) for vals in combinations(hi + lo, r=k))
```

This also returns both the product and the values that contributed to it (for inspection):

```py
>>> find_max_prod([-10, -10, 5, 2], k=3)
(500, (-10, -10, 5))

>>> find_max_prod([-10, -10, 7, 3, 1, 20, -30, 5, 2], k=3)
(6000, (-30, -10, 20))

>>> find_max_prod([-10, -10, 7, 3, 1, 20, -30, 5, 2], k=4)
(42000, (-30, -10, 20, 7))
```

## Speed

```py
n = 100_000
lst = np.random.randint(-20, 20, size=n).tolist()

%timeit find_max_prod(lst, 3)
# 5.7 ms ± 1.15 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

## Notes

- It works if there are no positive numbers (or no negative ones):

  ```py
  >>> find_max_prod([-1,-2,-1,-5], 3)
  (-2, (-1, -1, -2))

  >>> find_max_prod([5,6,7,8], 3)
  (336, (8, 7, 6))
  ```
- It works fine with floats as well:

  ```py
  >>> lst = np.random.normal(size=n).tolist()
  ... lst[:4]
  [-1.2645437227178908,
   0.04542859270503795,
   -0.17997935575118532,
   -0.03485546753207921]

  >>> find_max_prod(lst, 3)
  (72.00185172194192,
   (-4.159094140171658, -4.145875048073711, 4.175694390863968))
  ```

Answer (score -2):

Simple naive implementation (*O(n3)*):

```python
import itertools

def max_product_of_three(values):
    return max(
        x * y * z
        for x, y, z in itertools.combinations(values, 3)
    )
```

You can probably improve this by sorting values first.

---

Edit: here is a much more performant (*O(n)*) solution

```python
import heapq

def max_product_of_three(values):
    x, y, z = heapq.nlargest(3, values)
    a, b = heapq.nsmallest(2, values)

    return max(
        x * a * b,
        x * y * z
    )
```

Comment: How would sorting help?  (not that it wouldn't...but that's not enough by itself). Once the first combination of the thee values with the maximum abs value fails due to the sign of the result being wrong, what do you try next?   The trick is to know what the next highest product is without considering them all.  How is that done?

Comment: For instance, imagine you have a list of 1000 values. To find the max three-items product you do not have to try every combination, but only all combinations from the three largest values and two smallest (as in “large but negative”) values (that will only be taken both or none).